# Heroku and Vimeo conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, heroku, embed, vimeo

Yesterday (February 4, 2015 at 23:20:35 GMT-2) I received an email from an user frustrated that couldn't watch videos in my site (the focus point). All videos couldn't be watched and displayed an error, as seen in the image below:

[image: Emailed Image]

Videos are from Vimeo, and my site's on Heroku. As far as I can tell, the entire site was working, no error logs near that time (I even used it 30 minutes later and could watch the same videos the previous user was supposed to watch) Vimeo shows no error by that time too, the user just said every embed videos were displaying above message.

The weirdest thing is that Heroku is being mentioned inside Vimeo's box with the error.

I think that's very situational, but I'm not sure if it will happen again, can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently create a public domain name for your app and setup a DNS CNAME alias?

The issue you're describing sounds like you provisioned a new domain name for your app in Heroku, setup a DNS CNAME, and then your user clicked on the site before the DNS CNAME record had propagated out into the world properly.

This is an edge case that should only happen during the DNS CNAME TTL update (usually an hour).